# php variable scope is lost outside of php tags

Tags: php, tags, scope

When my php tags close and then reopen the variable information is lost and I have an error indicating that the variable is undefined.

For example this does not work:

```
<?php
$Header = array('TITLE' => 'Contact Us',);
?>
<? echo $Header['TITLE'] ?>
```

but this will work

```
<?php
$Header = array('TITLE' => 'Contact Us',);
echo $Header['TITLE'] ?>
```

There is something wrong with the installation / configuration of the php. I'm running php version 5.3.26 on windows 7.

Comment: Make sure you have short tags enabled in php.ini

Comment: @Let'sCode Then how it says `Undefined` ?

Comment: even better don't use them regardless of the php.ini settings

Comment: @Dagon it works without tyhe short tags. I kinda prefer using the short tags, so it would be nice if I could know how to enable them but in the meantime I can now continue coding, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because short tags are off.

In order to enable short tags, open your `php.ini` and search for `short_open_tag` and set it `on`.